# extracting embedded object elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object with embedded objects like this:

```
var object = { 'A' : 
                  {'cc' :  { 'cc data 1' : 'data 1 cc for A',
                             'cc data 2' : 'data 2 cc for A'
                           },
                   'dd' :   'data dd for A'
                  },
               'B' :
                  {'cc' : { 'cc data 1' : 'data 1 cc for B' ,
                            'cc data 2' : 'data 2 cc for B'
                          },
                   'dd' : 'data dd for B' 
                 }
            };
```

I wish to create another object for just the 'cc' data and skip the 'dd' data.  This code block illustrates what i am trying to do:

```
var newObj = {};
for ( key in object )   {
    newObj[key]             = {}                    ;
    newObj[key]['cc']       = {}                    ;
    newObj[key]['cc']       = object[key]['cc']     ;
}
console.log(util.inspect(newObj));
```

Is there a better way to do this?  i considered using pick but could not determine how.   I am thinking the solution might look something like this using a wildcard:

```
  _.pick(object[ * ], 'cc' )   // does not work
```

thank you.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and asking for better is rather opinionated.

Comment: That last edit of the data also changes the request/possibilities quite drastically. Must the data be a copy of the original, or are shared references ok? Is this a static structure, or can there be other dynamics that you haven't disclosed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce()`

```js
var object = {
  'A': {
    'cc': 'Data cc for A',
    'dd': 'Data dd for A'
  },
  'B': {
    'cc': 'Data cc for B',
    'dd': 'Data dd for B'
  }
};

var newObj = Object.keys(object).reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e] = {cc: object[e].cc};
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: interesting - i added a third level and tried your solution - it works on the third level as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is about as efficient as it's going to get, you could shorten it up a bit by not creating intermediate objects:

```
for (var key in object) {
  newObj[key] = {
    cc: object[key].cc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility in ES6. Better? Well that all depends on many things, including opinion.

```js
const javascriptObject = {
  'A': {
    'cc': 'Data cc for A',
    'dd': 'Data dd for A'
  },
  'B': {
    'cc': 'Data cc for B',
    'dd': 'Data dd for B'
  }
};
const myNewObject = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(javascriptObject)) {
  myNewObject[key] = Object.assign({}, javascriptObject[key]);
  delete myNewObject[key].dd;
}
console.log(myNewObject);
```